# Подключение SQLite к WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

У меня есть проект WinForms, так же написал бд в SQLite, как мне эту базу данных добавить в проект, чтобы потом с ней там работать?

Comment: Как пробовали? Это ведь элементарно и по первой ссылке в любом поисковике найдется решение. Ну допустим [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/21.1.php), пробовали? Думаю, нет...

Answer (score 2):

В этом пошаговом руководстве показано, как создать простое приложение Windows Forms (WinForms), поддерживаемое базой данных SQLite.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/get-started/winforms